# kafka machines in the cluster and kafka communications

Tags: apache-kafka

We have kafka cluster with 3 kafka brokers nodes and 3 zookeepers servers

kafka version - 10.1 ( hortonworks )

from my understanding since all meta data is located on the zookeeper servers , and kafka brokers are using this data ( kafka talk with zookeeper server via port 2181 )

I just wondering  if each kafka machine talk with other kafka in the cluster , or maybe kafka are get/put the data only on/from the zookeepers servers  ?

So dose kafka service need to communicate with other kafka in the cluster ? , 
Or maybe kafka machines get all is need only from the zookeepers server ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka brokers certainly need to communicate with each other, most importantly to replica data. Data produced to Kafka is replicated across brokers for fault-tolerance and data durability. Partition followers send `FetchRequest`s to partition leaders in order to replicate the data.

Additionally, the Controller broker sends a `LeaderAndIsr` request to brokers whenever a partition leader/follower is changed - that's how it informs brokers to start leading a partition or replicating it.

I would recommend these two introductory articles of mine in order to help you get more context:

https://hackernoon.com/thorough-introduction-to-apache-kafka-6fbf2989bbc1

https://hackernoon.com/apache-kafkas-distributed-system-firefighter-the-controller-broker-1afca1eae302

Comment: ok , in that case may I ask a diff question , we get the follwing errors about - ERROR [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-1011], Error for partition [topic1-example,34] to broker 1011:org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException: This server is not the leader for that topic-partition. (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)

Comment: do you think its something that realted to kafka combinations between machines OR kafka communication between the zookeepers servers ?

Comment: @Judy Both. Zookeeper maintains which broker is a leader. And the other brokers need to replicate from the leader. The error is from the `ReplicaFetcherThread`, which is from the broker itself, but it thought it needed to read from a particular leader, which is optained from Zookeeper. It might be possible that since you are running Kafka 0.10, you have hit a bug that has since been fixed in latest releases of Kafka

Comment: so in this case what is the latest kafka release that not allowed this issue ?

Comment: can you recommended on tool that can diagnostic problems on kafka ?